# Windows Access denied when installing azure package into virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, windows, azure, pip, virtualenv

under windows when I try to install the azure 4.0.0 package into a python virtualenv (3.x) using pip I get the following access denied error:

from my virtualenv directory

```
venv/Scripts/activate.bat
pip install azure==4.0.0
```

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\sklugr02\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-idfooing\azure_mgmt_network-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I also get the same error when trying to use PyCharm to install the package into a virtualenv

I tried using the --user option to pip install as instructed, but this is not a valid option when installing under a virtualenv. I get the following error:

from my virtualenv directory

```
venv/Scripts/activate.bat
pip install --user azure==4.0.0
```

ERROR: canot perform a '--user' install. User site-packages aer not visable in this virtualenv.

Also tried running the command prompt with admin rights but still get the same access denied error.

Ultimately, I want to use a requirements file to set up the virtualenv and have a line in it as:

azure==4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Since I wanted to use only BlockBlobService, I installed the azure-storage package. I faced the issue only for the azure package and not for other packages like azure-core, azure-storage, etc.